# DllMain() routine and MessageBox() function

Tags: c++

Is it true that **MessageBox**, as it is implemented in **User32.dll** in DllMain(), DllMain() routine could apparently be not invoked?
If yes, why? Could you explain?

> DllMain() has some limits for many useful things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call any function that could call loadlibrary of freelibray or you could create a dependency loop as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx).  It also just doesn't make sense.  Dll main should only be used to do some very limited initialization it is an entry point to your library not a place where logic should be executed

> During initial process startup or after a call to LoadLibrary, the
>   system scans the list of loaded DLLs for the process. For each DLL
>   that has not already been called with the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value,
>   the system calls the DLL's entry-point function. This call is made in
>   the context of the thread that caused the process address space to
>   change, such as the primary thread of the process or the thread that
>   called LoadLibrary. Access to the entry point is serialized by the
>   system on a process-wide basis. Threads in DllMain hold the loader
>   lock so no additional DLLs can be dynamically loaded or initialized.

Comment: Okay, so MessageBox() should not be called on DllMain()?

Comment: You are a genius! +1 ! Thanks :D

Comment: I have a doubt: is it true that if I insert MessageBox (as it shouldn't) should work (show) every time?

Comment: It could work if you are using the api thread and have already loaded everything you need.

Comment: ok, thank you. And why wouldn't it work if I'm not using the api thread?

Comment: @Yvanox it's not good to use any API from user32.dll in DLLMain(), it would make a deadlock situation and it's not safe. Statistically, if you'll use these function inside DLLMain(), `it could not make any difference if they are declared as WinAPI (__stcall). WinAPI indicates the __stdcall calling convention.`
But, a feature of __cdecl calling convention is that for such functions, the Variable Argument Lists can be used: this is not possible for __stdcall functions.
**Just don't use MessageBox - any api from user32.dll in DLLMain() routine**.